# чужой jquery ajax незнакомый синтаксис

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Что передается в data? pid:ppid что это может быть?

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/program/period',
            data: { pid: ppid },
            success: function(msg){
 alert( "Прибыли данные: " + msg );
 }
})
```

Comment: Все что угодно. Зависит от логики приложения.

Answer (score 1):

В data передается json объекта у которого есть поле pid.

Comment: есть какой-то объект со свойством pid, весь этот объект передается через json, верно?

Comment: да. Вместо этого pid может быть какое угодно поле, которое в т.ч. может содержать другой json объект или например массив.

Answer (score 1):

передаётся переменная ppid, определённая где-то выше в коде.
если ppid = 123,
то на сервер уйдёт объект с полем pid
{pid: 123}